# how do i get typeahead to return id instead of name in a json string array

Tags: json, return-value, typeahead, bootstrap-typeahead

Using bootstrap in Joomla. I've tried looking for a solution and tried a few differenet answers on here, but cant seem to get it working.

So far i've got the following to return the name but i want it to send the id rather than the name in the search input.

Here's what i have printed via php so far:

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {

        var artistData = [{"id":"3","artist_name":"DJ One"},{"id":"2","artist_name":"DJ Two"},{"id":"1","artist_name":"Another DJ"}];

        jQuery('#artist_id').typeahead({

        source: function(query, process) {
            artists = [];
             ids = {};

            jQuery.each(artistData, function(id, artist) {
                ids[artist.artist_name] = artist.id;
                artists.push(artist.artist_name);
            });
            process(artists);
        },
        matcher: function (item) {
            if (item.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.query.trim().toLowerCase()) != -1) {
                return true;
            }
        },

        sorter: function (items) {
            return items.sort();
        },
        updater: function (item) {
            selectedArtist = item.id;
            return item;
        }



        });


    });
```

I've tried various anwsers but this at least returns the `artist_name` but obviously that throws a mysql error. if i type in the id number into the input it works fine.

I just need to work out how to change the value to the id on submit. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is probably late, but there are a few mistakes happening here:

1. I am not sure where you are using `selectedArtist`, as it's not defined by anything visible.
2. In `matcher`, you never `return` for `false`. This may actually work out of coincidence as JavaScript will consider `undefined` as `false`.
3. You go through the effort of breaking apart the `artistData`, but you never actually use either array beyond that function explicitly (should be declared with `var` in that case rather than adding it to the global object by not using `var`).
4. Since you pass in the `artists` array to `process`, then any `item` passed around after that will just be an individual `string` contained by that array; it will not be a JSON object from the original array.

From there, you can reference [my answer on an otherwise similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16072956/how-to-avoid-to-display-json-string-with-custom-typeahead). Typeahead 2.x does not support using JSON objects by default, but it does support working with them if you override the `render` and `select` methods, which you must currently cheat to do (shown in the other answer).

At the end of it all, you then can do whatever you want within `updater` using the original JSON `item`s (e.g., `{"id":"3","artist_name":"DJ One"}`).  Therefore, you should probably `return item.artist_name` there, and likely set some global (I imagine you may already be trying to do this) to the value of `item.id` to track what is actually selected.

Also note: if--after the user has picked an `item` from the generated typeahead list--they *type* in an artist that does not exist in the database, then you *should* unset the global that you set in `updater` to avoid claiming `id`-whatever (e.g., 3) represents the unknown artist that they just typed in.