# How to avoid to display JSON string with custom typeahead

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-typeahead

I have overridden the typeahead methods to enable AJAX calls (getting JSON object results since I need a field `name` to display, and a field `url` to hide).

But it's not enough, everything works well when the user tape some research, but if you pick up a result, or just press `TAB`, there is the JSON string which appears in the input, something like:

```
{
    "name":"test",
    "url":"http://mysite.com/test"
}
```

I just want to display the field `name` in the input, like i do in the `dropbox` by overriding the `highlighter` method, but i don't know if it's possible.

```
highlighter: function (obj) 
{
    var item = JSON.parse(obj);
    var query = this.query.replace(/[\-\[\]{}()*+?.,\\\^$|#\s]/g, '\\$&')
    return item.name.replace(new RegExp('(' + query + ')', 'ig'), function ($1, match) 
    {
        return '<strong>' + match + '</strong>'
    });
}
```

Is there a way to do this simple thing?

I couldn't understand they provide methods we can override if we can't...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typeahead 2.x does not allow the storage or loading of JSON data by default. It looks like you're trying to work around that in your `highlighter` method with `JSON.parse`, but you could override a few methods similar to a [different question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16050356/make-twitter-bootstraps-typead-search-within-multiple-fields).

You can override almost any method within Typeahead, but you have to cheat to do it to the `render` and `select`, which you need to change from using `attr('data-value' ...)` to `data('value' ...)` as I did in the other answer.

Beyond that, you must change every single method that actively touches your JSON object: `highlighter`, `matcher`, `sorter`, and `updater`.

Because you only want to show the name in the highlight, you can avoid having to change `highlighter` by modifying `render` a little from the previous question:

```
typeahead.render = function(items) {
    var that = this

    items = $(items).map(function (i, item) {
        i = $(that.options.item).data('value', item)  // <- modified for data
        i.find('a').html(that.highlighter(item.name)) // <- modified for .name
        return i[0]
    });

    items.first().addClass('active')
    this.$menu.html(items)
    return this
};
```

Ignoring `select`, which I show in the other answer, you would still need to override `matcher`, `sorter`, and `updater`, which, including `highlighter`, can all be done through the passed in options:

```
var typeahead = $("#mytypeahead").typeahead({
    matcher: function (item) {
        return ~item.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.query.toLowerCase())
    },
    sorter: function (items) {
        var beginswith = []
            , caseSensitive = []
            , caseInsensitive = []
            , item

        while (item = items.shift()) {
            if (!item.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.query.toLowerCase())) beginswith.push(item)
            else if (~item.name.indexOf(this.query)) caseSensitive.push(item)
            // NOTE: they assume, by default, that all results contain the text
            else caseInsensitive.push(item)
        }

        return beginswith.concat(caseSensitive, caseInsensitive)
    },
    updater: function(item) {
        // NOTE: this is called when the user picks the option, so you can also
        //  use item.url here
        return item.name
    }
});
```

`sorter` is called after your overridden `source` method calls `process`, which kicks off everything else.